# C# WebClient downloads source for some pages, but not all

Tags: c#, webclient, http-status-code-403

I currently have this code that is supposed to grab the HTML source of the website. Specifically, I am telling it to read the source of 4chan. It **WILL** get the source code for a *board*, such as /pol/ or /news/, but it will **NOT** get the source code for *specific threads*. It throws the error: [System.Net.WebException: 'The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.']

Here is the code I am working with.

```
    public string GetSource(string url)
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12; //tried with & without this
        client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/6.0;)");
        try
        {
            return client.DownloadString(url);
        }
        catch
        {
            Error(2); //error code 2
        }
        return "";
    }
```

It will download the source of "https://boards.4chan.org/pol" for example.
It will not download the source of "https://boards.4chan.org/pol/thread/#"

I am completely lost as to how to proceed. I have a "user-agent" tag, and it works sometimes, so I don't know what the problem is. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The thread need an ID segment like `https://boards.4chan.org/pol/thread/252938557/`. Without them they return 403 from server.

Comment: That's what I've been doing. The "#" is just an abbreviation for simplicity sake. If you try requesting the source of a specific thread, it will return a 403 error.

Comment: yes then I tested it in Postman and it fully got all html result. What's your platform? .Net Core or .Net Framework or Standard?

Comment: I am using .Net Framework